# Dynamically inserting values while iterating over JSON object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I've gone too far down the rabbit hole for my skill level perhaps.

This is the JSON data I'm getting (it is a couple levels down.)

```
field_user_skill: {
    und: {
        0: {
            field_skill: { 
                und: "JavaScript" 
            },
            field_user_skill_current_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "5"
                }]
            },
            field_user_skill_desired_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "9"
                }]
            },
            remove_button: "Remove",
            _weight: 0
        },
        1: {
            field_skill: {
                und: "Ruby"
            },
            field_user_skill_current_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "6"
                }]
            },
            field_user_skill_desired_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "10"
                }]
            },
            remove_button: "Remove",
            _weight: 1
        },
    }
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can use specific value (from an array) eg. `var index = [0,1,2,3]` to iterate over the object and replace the IDs at each pass, and hopefully create a NEW array where i can compare the values of `field_user_skill_current_rating`, and `field_user_skill_desired_rating`.

For example, on the first pass, use the first index of `field_user_skill.und.0`, and then on the next pass using `field_user_skill.und.1`, and so on and so forth for each successive pass so I can create new arrays based on the results from each one.

I tried all the (crazy) ideas that popped into my head, but right now I'm stuck.

I'm just not really sure how to REPLACE values when iterating through using Javascript.  In fact, is that even possible?  I'm sorry for the formatting.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: look into underscore.js. it is a nice library with lots of ways to iterate over javascript objects. it will save you alot of headaches.

Comment: Show us some of the iterating code. And have you parsed the jSON? Do you have a javascript object that you are iterating through?

Comment: What kind of comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes your JSON never deviates from the above structure, so you should make sure this is the case, otherwise you'll need to add the proper existence checks before trying to access a property or an array value. You could probably do this all in one loop, but transforming the data makes it simpler to work with later on.

Also, I wasn't clear on what exactly you planned to do with this data, so I added an example. Hopefully this should give you a good starting point to accomplish what your after.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfPT5/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
var field_user_skill =  {
    und: {
        0: {
            field_skill: { 
                und: "JavaScript" 
            },
            field_user_skill_current_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "5"
                }]
            },
            field_user_skill_desired_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "9"
                }]
            },
            remove_button: "Remove",
            _weight: 0
        },
        1: {
            field_skill: {
                und: "Ruby"
            },
            field_user_skill_current_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "11"
                }]
            },
            field_user_skill_desired_rating: {
                und: [{
                    value: "10"
                }]
            },
            remove_button: "Remove",
            _weight: 1
        },
    }
};

function processSkills(userSkills){
    var data = [],
        skillNum = null; 

    for(skillNum in userSkills.und){
        data.push({
            'skill': userSkills.und[skillNum].field_skill.und,
            'currentRating': parseInt(userSkills.und[skillNum].field_user_skill_current_rating.und[0].value,10),
            'desiredRating': parseInt(userSkills.und[skillNum].field_user_skill_desired_rating.und[0].value,10),
        });
    }
    return data; 
}

function doYourComparison(data){

    var i = 0, 
        count = data.length;

    for(; i < count; i++){
        if(data[i].currentRating < data[i].desiredRating){
            alert('needs improvement'); 
        }else{
            alert('doint great'); 
        }
    }

}

var data = processSkills(field_user_skill);
doYourComparison(data);
```

**Results**

```
[
  {
    "skill": "JavaScript",
    "currentRating": 5,
    "desiredRating": 9
  },
  {
    "skill": "Ruby",
    "currentRating": 11,
    "desiredRating": 10
  }
]
```

Comment: I was a little vague, but your assumptions were close and got me right to where I needed to be!  I appreciate the help!  Now to just sort this in my AngularJS view template...